# creating a dynamic list of checkboxes based on array with options

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain to me please what is wrong with my javascript code, why can't I get this dropdown list with checkbox items to populate automatically after running this script:

```
<select id="myselect" name="myselect"></select>
```

as the html part,

...and below is the javascript:

```
    function populate(slct2) {
        var s2 = document.getElementById(myselect);
        s2.innerHTML = "";

        var optionArray = ["option1", "option2", "option2"];


        for (var option in optionArray) {

            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair;
            newOption.innerHTML = pair;
            s2.options.add(newOption);

    }
}
```

I also put it in a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9aZQF/339/
which is a simpler variant of another jsfiddle authored by someone else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myselect` should be wrapped in quotes - it's a string! And your fiddle never calls the function `populate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code - one might be specific to jsfiddle and not your actual code:

1. `myselect` is the id of your element, and `getElementById` expects this value *as a string*.
2. Your jsfiddle never calls the function `populate`
3. using `for...in` on an array will have some odd side effects - listing every function/internal property and value of the array. Lets work backwards.

Why `for..in` will give odd results when including mootools as mootools adds other properties to the `Array` object:

```js
var arr = ["One","Two", "Three"];
for(var item in arr){
  console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.js"></script>
```

Solve this by using `for...of` instead

```js
var arr = ["One","Two", "Three"];
for(let item of arr){
  console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.js"></script>
```

To solve number 2. just call your function:

```
populate();
```

To solve number 1, wrap the id of the select in quotes:

```
 var s2 = document.getElementById("myselect");
```

---

Here's the whole thing working:

```js
function populate() {
    var s2 = document.getElementById("myselect");
    s2.innerHTML = "";

    var optionArray = ["option1", "option2", "option2"];


  for (let option of optionArray) {

        var pair = option;
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair;
        newOption.innerHTML = pair;
        s2.options.add(newOption);

  }
}

populate();
```

```html
   Choose Subcategory:
<select id="myselect" name="myselect"></select>
```